# C# Uri Combine Different Kinds of BaseURL

Tags: c#

Let's say I have 3 different kinds of base url. It can be:

1. https://www.somewebsite.com/ OR https://www.somewebsite.com/doc/
2. C:\Files\Docs
3. https://www.somewebsite.com/doc?name=

I want to combine the base url with a constant part, in the form of `file.extension` (photo.jpg, doc.pdf...)

I'm using C#'s Uri to do this combine operation:

```cs
string baseUrl1 = "https://www.somewebsite.com/";
string baseUrl2 = "C:\Files\Docs";
string baseUrl3 = "https://www.somewebsite.com/doc?name=";

string fileName = "doc.pdf";

Uri baseUri = new Uri(baseUrl1);
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, fileName);
Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());
```

I'm getting:

```
1: https://www.somewebsite.com/doc.pdf
2: file:///C:/Files/Docs/1cy1ipsf.pdf
3: https://www.somewebsite.com/doc.pdf (I expected: https://www.somewebsite.com/doc?name=doc.pdf)
```

In the third case, how do I maintain the URL queries?

Comment: It is a string so simply use a plus sign to combine two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to just concatenate the strings together? And create the new URL from it. So it would be:

```
string baseUrl1 = "https://www.somewebsite.com/";
string baseUrl2 = "C:\Files\Docs";
string baseUrl3 = "https://www.somewebsite.com/doc?name=";

string fileName = "doc.pdf";

Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUrl1 + fileName);
Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());
```

If you want to add an extra check if the URI end with or without a / you could add something like:

```
(baseUrl1.Substring(str.Length-1) == "/") ? "" : "/"
```

So it could look like:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUrl1 + (baseUrl1.Substring(baseUrl1.Length-1) == "/") ? "" : "/" + fileName);
```

Comment: But that doesn't prevent certain cases where the url doesn't have the slash. Like http://www.somewebsite.comdoc.pdf

Comment: @EnzoMatheus I edited the answer. It isn't the most elegant solution, but it is a solution which would work